# How to avoid null field values in Laravel relation

Tags: laravel, null, relation

I have code like this:

```php
return $client->general;
```

where general is hasOne relation to Client. Now, how can I avoid sending attributes where value is NULL or empty string. Beacuse General table has a lot columns and I don't want to send all values if some of them are NULL or empty string.

EDIT:
Right now, I'm using this solution, but is there a better way to do it?

```php
foreach($client->general->toArray() as $key => $value) {
   if($value === null || $value === "") {
      unset($client->general[$key]);
   }
}
return $client->general;
```

Comment: show us what you have tried!

Comment: Updated first post

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve all the values of the general first and check if the value is null. If it is not null, store key value in the array.

```
$general = $client->general->toArray();

$newGeneral = [];

foreach($general as $key => $value){
    if (is_null($value) === false) {
        $newGeneral[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```